# Subscribe to the CATIA specification tree changing event

Tags: catia, caa

Is there a way to subscribe to the changes in the CATIA specification tree and save that changes to some log file? As far as I understand, I probably need to use `CATIModelEvents` or `CATEventSubscriber` but how can I reach the tree itself?

P.S> Actually, all I need is to get times, when user made some changes to the part or product, so any tip or help about how to reach that is appreciated

Comment: Have you found a solution in this case?

Comment: @Radogost yes looks like it's only possible with CAA-RADE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of researching, I came to a conclusion that it's only possible with CAA-RADE